# Quadratic equation of characteristic 2 and Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

I have a problem and the problem is:

> Let $F$ be a field and char $F$=2.Let $$E=F[x]/(x^2+bx+c)~~b,c\in F.$$
>
> When $b$ and $c$ satisfy what condition, $E$ is a Galois extension with $[E:F]=2$.

My opinion:

Firstly $x^2+bx+c$ should an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$.

Then in  $E$ , $x^2+bx+c$ should have two different roots.

$E$ is  splitting field over $F$ with a separable polynomial, so  $E/F$ is a Galois extension with $[E:F]=2$

But how to find the specific conditions which $b$ and $c$ should satisfy?

Thanks!

Comment: Separability is equivalent to $b\neq 0$. For irreducibility I see no better condition than $F$ having no element $y$ satisfying $y^2+y +cb^{-2}=0$. (Make the variable change $x=by$ in $x^2+bx+c$.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290003

Comment: See [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4392472/11619) for an exposition of how solvability of a quadratic is determined over a finite field of characteristic two. At heart it is the idea in @Claudius's comment. But in the case of finite fields we can describe the solvability condition using the trace function, which is often handy. This is also a case of [Artin-Schreier theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory) in action.